# java android: res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.], cant fix

Tags: java, android

i am getting:

```
[2012-06-10 12:47:39 - pet_game] Launch canceled!
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\Restaurant-Blue-2-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-06-10 12:49:13 - pet_game] res\drawable-hdpi\baseball-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

I know this is due to the fact that i have upper case letter in the image file name so I deleted those two files. However, I still get same error. I tried to refresh the entire project and restarting eclipse, but it didnt help. what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use: `-`. Instead use: `_`.

Comment: i deleted those two files, they dont exist in my project but i still get this error, thats my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Uppercases are not allowed for resource names. Only lowercases(a-z), numbers0-9, .(dot) and _(underscore)are valid.
Use `Restaurant_Blue_2_icon.png` and `baseball_icon.png` for the image names.

Answer (score 0):

`baseball-icon.png` is too invalid name change it to `baseball_icon.png` and you are good to go.